# Fatal error class MainController not found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

so i have the following structure for what i'm trying to target but what i'm getting is the `Fatal error class MainController not found` , i'm new to autoload and namespace thing (but getting into them fast) i just need to know why this is happening , hope you guys have bit explained situation for me? i did saw few of answer around stackoverflow but nuthing helped, i know i'm doing something really wrong, but thats how i will learn :).   structure:

```
composer.json

src/controllers/MainController.php
```

the following is my autoload inside composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
       "controllers\\": "src/controllers/"
     }
}
```

and this is how my MainController.php looks alike :

```
namespace MainController;

class MainController{

  function test($name){

    echo 'holaaaa'.$name;

  }

}
```

controller call inside: app/loads/loadController.php :::

```
use MainController;

$MainController = new MainController();
```

more info on vendor/autoload.php

it's included inside : index.php and inside index.php i have included mainapp.php and inside mainapp.php i have included loadcontroller.php vich calls the controller

structure screenshot:

[image: this is the sreenshot of where files are located.]

Comment: How do you call the controller?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, in your Composer file you say the namespace is `controllers`. In your PHP file you say the namespace is `MainController`. They need to be the same for the autoloading to work.

If we are to go by your Composer file then the PHP should look like this:

```
namespace controllers;
class MainController {}
```

And the class should be called like this:

```
$MainController = new \controllers\MainController;
```

Or like this:

```
use controllers\MainController;
$MainController = new MainController;
```

Or, if you want a nicer-looking class name:

```
use controllers\MainController as Controller;
$MainController = new Controller;
```

Comment: this is what i get : `Fatal error: Class 'controllers\MainController' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drive/app/loads/loadController.php on line 3`  still doing something wrong i think :O

Comment: Try to run this in your terminal: `composer dump-autoload` (or `php composer.phar dump-autoload` if you are using the PHAR version).

Comment: did that already and updated the composer as well. but it says same thing ,, maybe can be how i'm calling the controller? ,, i have added the path of file where i'm calling the controller.

Comment: Have you included the `./vendor/autoload.php` file? That is the file that actually autoloads your classes.

Comment: yes i have included it, it's included inside : `index.php`  and inside `index.php `i have included `mainapp.php`  and inside `mainapp.php` i have included `loadcontroller.php` vich calls the controller.

Comment: Then I am not sure what is wrong. Are you 100% sure the `MainController.php` file exists? Maybe there is a typo in the file or folder name? What do you get if you type this into your terminal: `find`.

Comment: i have added a screenshot of my structure (real one) from editor. check the question

Comment: with find in terminal i get : find: MainController.php: No such file or directory   pretty strange cause the file is there with correct name

Comment: with : find /Applications/Mamp/htdocs/drive -name "MainController.php"   i do  get the following :: 

/Applications/Mamp/htdocs/drive/app/controllers/MainController.php

Comment: @Arsh Open `vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`. Add `var_dump($file);` to the end of the `loadClass()` method. Reload the page and see which file the autoloader is trying to load. If you do not get anything then it means the autoloader has not been loaded.

Comment: got this when i did var_dump($file);  : string(69) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drive/vendor/controllers/MainController.php"  and many other strings with different files

Comment: Well, there is the problem! It is using the wrong path. This discussion is getting a little long. Maybe you can find some help in the [PHP chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only managed to correct it after deleting my folder from the composer (**vendor**) and rerunning the command **composer dump-autoload**